# How to execute a JavaScript in a URL

Tags: javascript

I need to execute a certain JavaScript when accesing the custom URL.

At this time the code behind the button that triggers the JavaScript that I need to be ran is this:

```
  <a class="button" href="#" 

  onclick="new Request.HTML({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/ro/somefolder/anotherfolder',
  data: {'user_id': 777, 'score': 1, 'redirect': '1'},
  update: $('vote_user_777'),
  evalScripts: true
}).send();return false;">

<img src="/images/game/thumbsup.gif" alt="vote">
</a>

</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific as to what you're problem is? I'm sorry, I'm having difficulty understanding what's wrong.

Comment: I said that on the website there is a button which when pressed triggers that JavaScript, all i want is a custom URL ( page URL + something ) to execute that JavaScript, the second is accesed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say what problem you were experiencing, but the syntax looks like the MooTools library.

So I put together a little Javascript that should work, and is more in line with MooTools style.

```
  window.addEvent('domready',function() {
    var request = new Request.HTML({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/ro/somefolder/anotherfolder',
        data: {'user_id': 777, 'score': 1, 'redirect': '1'},
        update: $('vote_user_777'),
        evalScripts: true
    });
    $$('a.button').addEvent('click',function(e) {
        e.stop();
        request.send();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to embedding your JavaScript in a URL rather than attaching it as an event handler, you could do something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(new Request.HTML({...}).send())">
```

Using the `void()` function ensures that nothing is returned so that the browser does not navigate away from the current page.

Comment: The return false statement in his function already takes care of that.

Comment: Yes, but if he's trying to embed his script in a URL, returning false will either generate an error or take you to a page named "false". When using a `javascript:` URL, you should wrap it in `void()` instead.

Comment: Actually, when the onclick handler returns false, it doesn't execute it's default, which is traveling to the href.

Comment: Yes… I realize that. You'll note that the example code I provided doesn't *have* an onclick handler. This is *instead of* an onclick handler, as stated in my answer.